# Laravel 5 - Eloquent relationships returning empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

this is my first time trying out eloquent relationships. I've looked at multiple tutorials already.

I have two tables. Albums and Artists. An Artist can have many Albums. An Album can only have one Artist.

Here are the two Schemas and Models for both of these.

**Artist Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Artist extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'Artists';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['artist_name', 'artist_image_loc', 'followers'];

    public function albums()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Album');
    }
}
```

**Album Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Album extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'Albums';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['album_name', 'album_image_loc', 'artist_id'];

    public function artists()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Artist');
    }
}
```

**Artist Schema**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArtistsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Artists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('artist_name');
            $table->string('artist_image_loc');
            $table->integer('followers');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('Artists');
    }
}
```

**Album Schema**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAlbumsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('album_name');
            $table->string('album_image_loc');
            $table->integer('artist_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('artist_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('Artists');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('Albums');
    }
}
```

I have one album and one artist sitting in the database, with the album's artist_id set to the artist's id.

```
>>> $album = new App\Album;
=> App\Album {#694}
>>> $album->artists()->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#704
     all: [],
   }
```

I need to find out why these are returning empty.

Thanks for any help!
Toby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say that an Artist can have many Albums, then, on the Artist class you should have this:

```
public function albums()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Album');
}
```

And, if an Album can only have one Artist, then, on the Album class you should have this:

```
public function artist()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Artist');
}
```

On your code you did just the opposite.

To retrieve the artist from an album you only need to do this:

```
$album->artist;
```

And to retrieve the albums from an artist:

```
$artist->albums;
```

So, you don't need to call the method, you can use eloquent's dynamic properties (in this case, artist and album)
You can find more information here:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships